# LazyPredict: Found array with 0 features

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am testing [lazypredict](https://github.com/shankarpandala/lazypredict/) with my own data.

The problem is that all the classifiers see 0 features in the input dataframe.
Thus it shows only the DummyClassifier.

The behaviour is the same with random boolean data like in this snippet:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([True, False], size=(10, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([True, False], size=(10, 1)), columns=list('F'))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.5, random_state=123)
clf = LazyClassifier(verbose=0, ignore_warnings=False, custom_metric=None)
models, predictions = clf.fit(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
print(models)
```

Here the output with all classifiers not seeing the features:

```
AdaBoostClassifier model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by AdaBoostClassifier.
BaggingClassifier model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by BaggingClassifier.
BernoulliNB model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by BernoulliNB.
CalibratedClassifierCV model failed to execute
n_splits=5 cannot be greater than the number of members in each class.
CategoricalNB model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by CategoricalNB.
DecisionTreeClassifier model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by DecisionTreeClassifier.
  0%|          | 0/29 [00:00<?, ?it/s]ExtraTreeClassifier model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by ExtraTreeClassifier.
ExtraTreesClassifier model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by ExtraTreesClassifier.
GaussianNB model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by GaussianNB.
KNeighborsClassifier model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by KNeighborsClassifier.
LabelPropagation model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by LabelPropagation.
LabelSpreading model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by LabelSpreading.
LinearDiscriminantAnalysis model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.
LinearSVC model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by LinearSVC.
LogisticRegression model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by LogisticRegression.
NearestCentroid model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by NearestCentroid.
NuSVC model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by NuSVC.
PassiveAggressiveClassifier model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by PassiveAggressiveClassifier.
Perceptron model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by Perceptron.
QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis.
RandomForestClassifier model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by RandomForestClassifier.
RidgeClassifier model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by RidgeClassifier.
RidgeClassifierCV model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by RidgeClassifierCV.
SGDClassifier model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by SGDClassifier.
SVC model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by SVC.
StackingClassifier model failed to execute
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'estimators'
XGBClassifier model failed to execute
[10:39:24] /workspace/src/data/iterative_dmatrix.cc:202: Check failed: n_features >= 1 (0 vs. 1) : Data must has at least 1 column.
Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) /home/enrico/.miniconda3/envs/xgb/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x3ef8ea) [0x7f51962cd8ea]
  [bt] (1) /home/enrico/.miniconda3/envs/xgb/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x3f52e7) [0x7f51962d32e7]
  [bt] (2) /home/enrico/.miniconda3/envs/xgb/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x3f8188) [0x7f51962d6188]
  [bt] (3) /home/enrico/.miniconda3/envs/xgb/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x3a2367) [0x7f5196280367]
  [bt] (4) /home/enrico/.miniconda3/envs/xgb/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(XGQuantileDMatrixCreateFromCallback+0x2b0) [0x7f5196043ab0]
  [bt] (5) /home/enrico/.miniconda3/envs/xgb/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/../../libffi.so.6(ffi_call_unix64+0x4c) [0x7f51c713d630]
  [bt] (6) /home/enrico/.miniconda3/envs/xgb/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/../../libffi.so.6(ffi_call+0x22d) [0x7f51c713cfed]
  [bt] (7) /home/enrico/.miniconda3/envs/xgb/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x1084a) [0x7f51c715184a]
  [bt] (8) /home/enrico/.miniconda3/envs/xgb/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x10f63) [0x7f51c7151f63]


100%|██████████| 29/29 [00:00<00:00, 303.17it/s]
LGBMClassifier model failed to execute
Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(5, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
                 Accuracy  Balanced Accuracy  ROC AUC  F1 Score  Time Taken
Model                                                                      
DummyClassifier      0.20               0.50     0.50      0.07        0.02
```

However [the example](https://lazypredict.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#classification) works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, bool data frames are not allowed by lazypredict (IDK other classifiers but XGBoost is perfectly fine with them).

The simplest solution I found is to convert the boolean DataFrames to int with `astype(int)`.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([True, False], size=(10, 3)), columns=list('ABC')).astype(int)
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([True, False], size=(10, 1)), columns=list('F')).astype(int)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.5, random_state=123)
clf = LazyClassifier(verbose=0, ignore_warnings=False, custom_metric=None)
models, predictions = clf.fit(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
print(models)
```